# Resize images before sending to Server PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a file upload html control on my form like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="FormReceiver.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto"  />
</form>
```

Is there anyway, I can resize this image before sending it to server and then after receiving on server can i resize it again to origional size?

Actually the users of my site will browsing this page on mobile, so it takes very long to upload images on mobile device.

Comment: what you could do is resize before displaying , and storing the original full resolution image with a data attribute or hidden input element and receive it on php......resizing from low res to high is not same as high to low . The Quality is lost ...

Comment: Actually, I only need to store this image to DB. No need to display it on page. How can i resize before sending it to server? I think some JS will do this job. any ideas??

Comment: Use the [GD-library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: @NidaSulheri If you Find The Answer is correct then accept it, since it would be removed from unanswered list of questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HTML5` to resize and then upload Have a look at this article [**link**](http://www.rubydesigner.com/blog/resizing-images-before-upload-using-html5-canvas).

`HTML5`: Image resizing is **only possible** on **Firefox 3.5+** and only at a fixed quality. **WebKit/Opera doesn't support direct data access to the selected files**.

The rest it handles with Flash.

Answer (score -2):

you can resize it with [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which is built in with php.

After it has uploaded to tmp file, resize it and save it to your desired place.

Comment: The OP wants to resize before uploading, i.e. client side. GD won't be of any help for that.